# DOMPDF: Why is CSS not rendering properly to PDF while splitting page in half?

Tags: html, css, pdf, dompdf

Is there a different way of going about my CSS?

I've got some html code along with some CSS styling trying to generate a PDF where my sample text container/div is floating right. If I load the html site up itself, the CSS is all correct and looks fine. But when I convert from the code to PDF file, it outputs wrong. Can anyone suggest a way which would work?

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page {
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        #top,
        #bottom {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 50%;
        }
        #top {
            top: 0;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        #bottom {
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: green;
        }
        div.mainLayout{position: relative;float:right;width:50%;height:100%;}
        .textstuff {
            background-color:aqua;
            left:0;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div class="mainLayout">
            <div class="textstuff">
                <center>
                    <font size="5" style="padding-bottom:5px">Sample Text 1</font><br />
                    <font size="4" style="padding-bottom:5px">Sample Text 2</font><br />
                    <font size="5" style="padding-bottom:25px">Sample Text 3</font><br />
                    <font size="4">Sample Text 4</font>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <div class="mainLayout">
            <div class="textstuff">
                <center>
                    <font size="5" style="padding-bottom:5px">Sample Text 1</font><br />
                    <font size="4" style="padding-bottom:5px">Sample Text 2</font><br />
                    <font size="5" style="padding-bottom:25px">Sample Text 3</font><br />
                    <font size="4">Sample Text 4</font>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is being rendered as HTML file (correct):
[image: What is being output via HTML]

What is being rendered as PDF file (output is incorrect, should be like what's above):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the CSS to work on the PDF:

```
<style>
    @page {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #top, #bottom {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 50%;
    }
    #top {
        top: 0;
    }
    #bottom {
        bottom: 0;
    }
    div.mainLayout{height:100%;}
    .communitylogotop {
        bottom: 41px;
    }
    .text {
        margin-right:50px;
        margin-top:65px;
        width:44%;
        float:right;
    }
</style>
```

And my body now looks like this:

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="mainLayout">
        <div class="text">
            HERE's..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <div class="mainLayout">
        <div class="text">
            ...STUFF
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```